# Flask mysql query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn) TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I tried almost everything to make my first flask task work on cloud9 but still gives me this error

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO studentmaster 
                       (Student_Id,Student_FirstName,Student_LastName,
                        Course_Id,Gender,Residential_Address,
                        PhoneNo,Email,Password) 
                  VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''',
               (stid,firstname, lastname, coursename, gender, address,
                phone, email,password))
```

here is the link to my app 
https://ide.c9.io/hunteelar/studentregistration#openfile-README.md

Comment: Not very familiar with the syntax, but this could be because you have 9 variables and only 7 `%s` parameters in VALUES

Answer (score 2):

you have 9 column in table name 9 var in values but only 7 %s in values ( %s......%s)

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO studentmaster 
  (Student_Id,Student_FirstName,Student_LastName,Course_Id,Gender,Residential_Address,PhoneNo,Email,Password) 
  VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)',
  (stid,firstname, lastname, coursename, gender, address,phone, email,password))
```